# Why I get "Undefined variable" in Laravel view?

Tags: php, templates, laravel, undefined

when I try to fetch data from table where categories are I get Undefined variable: category error.

$posts variable work fine.

```
@if(count($posts))

@foreach($posts as $post)
    @if($post->category)
        <div class="{{ $post->category->name }} isotope-item">
                <img src="../img/showcase/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="disp-post">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <p class="time">{{ $post->updated_at }}</p>
                    <h4>{{ Str::words($post->title, 3) }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ Str::words($post->body, 60) }}</p>
                    <p class="link">{{ HTML::linkRoute('posts.show', 'Read more', array($post->id)) }}</p>
                 </div>
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
@endif
```

but when i try $category:

```
@if(count($category))
    @foreach($category as $c)
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="{{ $c->name }}">Networking</a></li>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

I get an error.

What am I doing wrong?

This is from my PostsController

```
public function showcase()
{
    $category = Category::all();
    $posts = Post::with('category')->orderBy('updated_at')->get();
    return View::make('posts.showcase', compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: you are getting error because `$category` is not available in you view, try `return View::make('posts.showcase', compact('posts','category'));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not passing the `$category` variable to your view, you're just passing `$posts`.

Change your line:

```php
return View::make('posts.showcase', compact('posts'));
```

To be:

```php
return View::make('posts.showcase', compact('posts', 'category'));
```

And your `$category` variable will be available.