# Error : undefined variable in laravel view

Tags: laravel, view

I am getting this error: undefined variable. I read a lot of posts about it but, none of them helped with the problem i am facing. ([Why I get "Undefined variable" in Laravel view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341009/why-i-get-undefined-variable-in-laravel-view) )

This is Project_Controller :

```
class Project_Controller extends Controller
{

public function create()
{
$arrondissement = Arrondissements::pluck('arrondissement', 'id');

return view::make('projets.create', compact('arrondissement'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'intitule' => 'required|max:255',
        'code' => 'required|max:255',
        'dateDebut' => 'required|max:255',
        'dateFin' => 'required|max:255',
        'estimation' => 'required|max:255',
        'arrondissement' => $request->arrondissement,
    ]);     
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()
        ->withInput()
        ->with(['arrondissement'=>$arrondissement])
        ->withErrors($validator);
}               
    $projet = new Projet;

    $projet->intitule = $request->intitule;
    $projet->code = $request->code;
    $projet->dateDebut = $request->dateDebut;
    $projet->dateFin = $request->dateFin;
    $projet->estimation = $request->estimation;
    $projet->arrondissement = $request->arrondissement;


    $projet->save();

     return view('/submit', compact('arrondissement'));     
}
}
```

submit.blade.php :

```
    <select name="arrondissement_id">
        @if (!empty($arrondissement))                   
            Whoops! Something went wrong                
        @else
            @foreach($arrondissement as $id => $arrondissement)
                <option value="{{$id}}">{{$arrondissement}}</option>                    
            @endforeach
        @endif
</select>
```

and this is routes.php :

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/', function () {
   $projets = \App\Projet::all();
   return view('welcome', compact('projets'));
});

Route::get('/submit', function () {
return view('submit');
});

Route::post('submit/projects', 'Project_Controller@store');
```

I can't see what's causing this error ??

I am using 'arrondissement' as a foreign key of table 'arrondissements'

Comment: Your Project_Controller (as posted) is broken php. You start method `store()` before ever ending the method `create()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It's simple, I had to remove exclamation mark. Because, I need to test if the value is empty not unempty.

Answer (score 2):

When returning the view, you should also pass the variable with data:

```
$arrondissement = ....

return view('/submit', compact('arrondissement'));
```

Comment: I already did in 'create' method...I tried it, but still not working

Comment: @Naj you also loading the view in the `store` method and in a closure in routes file.

Comment: I don't get it, I shouldn't load the view in the store ?

Comment: @Naj you can redirect user, like `return redirect()->back()`. But if you've loading a view which works with some variables, these variables shouldn't be empty. Or, you could just check if variable is empty, like `@if (!empty($arrondissement)) do some stuff with data @endif`

Comment: Please chek the post I edited it, I addedd @if and else, and I also insert some data into "arrondissements" table in database

Answer (score 0):

```
public function create(){
    $data = [];
    $kategoris = Kategori::orderBy('kategori', 'ASC')->get();
    $data['kategoris'] = $kategoris; 
    return view('backend.produk.create', $data);
}
```

```
@if (count($kategoris) > 0)
    @foreach($kategoris as $kategori)
        <option value="{{ $kategori->id }}">{{ $kategori->kategori }}</option>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$arrondissement = Arrondissements::pluck('arrondissement', 'id');
```

You should also add this line into the store function